# I want to make my unity 2d scene completely dark so I can light it with my own lighting

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have tried making the skybox black but that does not work bc my sprites are still showing.

Comment: The default sprite renderer does not react to illumination. Search for the topic of 2D illumination. There are some tutorials on that.

Answer (score -1):

Here are tutorial on 2D lighting
https://unity.com/how-to/use-2d-lights-unity-set-mood